# Pre-compute random variable with same expected value and variance

Tags: random-variable, exponential-distribution

Say I have an exponential distribution with parameter lambda λ.
Is there a way to generate 100-500 pre-computed values that when summed, have the same variance and mean as the exponential (and the same distribution). How can I:

1. generate these values?
2. prove that they fit an exponential distribution?

*One possible solution:* generate the values to simulate maybe 10 million values and then group them into buckets somehow? Is there a good algorithm for this? I figure if this is done right, part 2 is not that necessary.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "when summed"?  That phrase indicates you have a *single* value -- the sum -- which leaves us wondering what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

```
######################################
# PARAMETERS & INITIALIZATION        #

lambda <- 10
M <- 1000
set.seed(1)

######################################
# SIMULATION                         #

E <- rexp(1,lambda)   # one exponential random variable
U <- runif(M)         # M uniform random variables
X <- E * U / sum(U)   # M random variables satisfying the requirements
```

Comment: can you add some annotations my good sir?

Comment: Comments added.

Comment: what language is this Julia or R or something?

Comment: This is R but the idea is to show you a simple algorithm which you can implement in a language of your choice.

Comment: I don't know R, but you are storing 1000 U's in one variable called U? is it an array? and if it's an array, how are you doing `E*U`, if U is an array? and what sense does `E*U` make anyway? I think the last line needs more explanation..at least for me.

Comment: The few variable manipulations I have utilized are quite standard across R, Matlab, Python, Stata, etc. You do need to learn at least one statistical language before asking the questions like the one above. In particular, this tutorial (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/index.htm) will get you going in no time.

Comment: Ok sure, but please explain the logic/reasoning in the last line ty ty

Comment: $M$ uniform random variables (as a vector) rescaled by scalars to sum up to an exponential random variable.

Comment: This standardizes the mean, but how do you achieve the requirement on the variance??

Comment: Both mean and variance of an exponential random variable are dictated by $\lambda$. The procedure ensures the simulated random variables sum up to Exp($\lambda$).

Comment: You appear to generate a certain number of *correlated* variates whose sum, a single number, is a realization of an exponential random variable.  Although I can see how one might interpret the question in such a way as to make that a correct response, I doubt that's what the OP intends.  It leaves in abeyance the meaning of "precompute" and makes one wonder about the speculation in the question about "grouping into buckets."